# Cannot open enterprise geodatabase table from workspace

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, enterprise-geodatabase, flask

I'm trying to create a REST Flask API to use instead of geoprocessing with the toolbox. Using the ArcGIS Python environment, I was able to make use of the libraries in Flask, but I'm facing a problem related to the files.

I'm trying to do a search in an enterprise geodatabase table through ArcPy, but the script returns that it's not possible to open the file.

Flask Controler:

```
@api.route('/api/v1/geoportal/evaluation-form')
class EvaluationForm(Resource):
    def post(self):
        system = request.args.get('system')
        form = api.payload
        res = insertSystemFormAnswers(system, form, db)
        return res, 200
```

insertSystemFormAnswers method:

```
def insertSystemFormAnswers(system, form, db):
    # inserting into sde database
    fc = u'\\\\HAB2VMSV014\\geoprocessing_tools\\connections\\Servidor_28_app_documentos_emitidos.sde'
    workspace = os.path.dirname(fc)
    edit = arcpy.da.Editor(workspace)
    edit.startEditing(False, False)
    edit.startOperation()
    registryId = None

    if form.has_key('nome'): form.pop('nome')
    if form.has_key('email'): form.pop('email')

    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(u'\\\\HAB2VMSV014\\geoprocessing_tools\\connections\\Servidor_28_app_documentos_emitidos.sde','*') as searchCursor:
        for row in searchCursor:
            print(row)
```

Error:

> RuntimeError: cannot open '\HAB2VMSV014\geoprocessing_tools\connections\Servidor_28_app_documentos_emitidos.sde'

What is wrong here?

---

@fezter Sorry, I made a mistake when writing the code here.

The search cursor was already pointing to the desired table but the error shown is the same. I did what you advised and nothing changed.

The code was like this:

```
geodb_conn = u'\\\\HAB2VMSV014\\geoprocessing_tools\\connections\\Servidor_28_app_documentos_emitidos.sde'
arcpy.env.workspace = geodb_conn
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(os.path.join(arcpy.env.workspace, 'sde.portalweb.TB_AVALIACAO'),'*') as searchCursor:
    for row in searchCursor:
        print(row)
```

And the error remains the same:

> RuntimeError: cannot open '\HAB2VMSV014\geoprocessing_tools\connections\Servidor_28_app_documentos_emitidos.sde\sde.portalweb.TB_AVALIACAO'

Remembering that I'm trying to do this using flask. Out of flask the code works perfectly

Comment: The key here is that a connection file is a ***folder***. You can use it as a target when the parameter is a `workspace`, but not when the source is a `layer`.

Answer (score 1):

You are defining fc to be the connection to the geodatabase. Typically, fc is a variable name for "feature class". Feature classes reside inside the geodatabase.

I would change this line:

```
fc = u'\\\\HAB2VMSV014\\geoprocessing_tools\\connections\\Servidor_28_app_document
```

To this:

```
geodb_conn = u'\\\\HAB2VMSV014\\geoprocessing_tools\\connections\\Servidor_28_app_documentos_emitidos.sde'
```

Then you can have:

```
arcpy.env.workspace = geodb_conn
```

That will set your workspace to the geodatabase connection file.

Next, as per the [documentation](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-data-access/searchcursor-class.htm), your search cursor should point to a feature class or table. The way you've got it set up, you're pointing to the database connection.

So, if you only want to search a single table or feature class, you can have something like this:

```
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(os.path.join(workspace, FCNAME),'*') as searchCursor:
        for row in searchCursor:
            print(row)
```

where `FCNAME` is the name of your feature class.

Alternatively, you could iterate over all feature classes by nesting the search cursor in a for loop.

```
for FCNAME in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses():
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(os.path.join(workspace, FCNAME),'*') as searchCursor:
            for row in searchCursor:
                print(row)
```

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake when writing the code here.

The search cursor was already pointing to the desired table but the error shown is the same. I did what you advised and nothing changed.


The code was like this:
`
    geodb_conn = u'\\\\HAB2VMSV014\\geoprocessing_tools\\connections\\Servidor_28_app_documentos_emitidos.sde'
    arcpy.env.workspace = geodb_conn
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(os.path.join(arcpy.env.workspace, 'sde.portalweb.TB_AVALIACAO'),'*') as searchCursor:
        for row in searchCursor:
            print(row)
`